# What makes a log event id unique in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, microsoft-extensions-logging, asp.net-core-logging

When logging w/ event id's like this: `logger.LogInformation(1001, "Getting item {Id}", id);`

How do I query a [semantic or structured log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging), for those events?  What are the key(s)?  I'm guessing `EventId.Id` + `SourceContext`?  (There's no guarantee the id I want to use isn't used by some other library so I must have to use `EventId.Id` plus some other field, right?)

When reviewing the official docs, [Log event ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#log-event-id), I didn't see any recommendations on this topic.  I only found this:

> Some logging providers store the event ID in a field, which allows for filtering on the ID.